# How to bundle many files in S3 using Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I have 20 million files in S3 spanning roughly 8000 days.

The files are organized by timestamps in UTC, like this: `s3://mybucket/path/txt/YYYY/MM/DD/filename.txt.gz`.  Each file is UTF-8 text containing between 0 (empty) and 100KB of text (95th percentile, although there are a few files that are up to several MBs).

Using Spark and Scala (I'm new to both and want to learn), I would like to save "daily bundles" (8000 of them), each containing whatever number of files were found for that day. Ideally I would like to store the original filenames as well as their content.  The output should reside in S3 as well and be compressed, in some format that is suitable for input in further Spark steps and experiments.

One idea was to store bundles as a bunch of JSON objects (one per line and `'\n'`-separated), e.g.

```
{id:"doc0001", meta:{x:"blah", y:"foo", ...}, content:"some long string here"}
{id:"doc0002", meta:{x:"foo", y:"bar", ...}, content: "another long string"}
```

Alternatively, I could try the Hadoop SequenceFile, but again I'm not sure how to set that up elegantly.

Using the Spark shell for example, I saw that it was very easy to read the files, for example:

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("s3n://mybucket/path/txt/1996/04/09/*.txt.gz")
// or even
val textFile = sc.textFile("s3n://mybucket/path/txt/*/*/*/*.txt.gz")
// which will take for ever
```

But how do I "intercept" the reader to provide the file name?

Or perhaps I should get an RDD of all the files, split by day, and in a reduce step write out `K=filename, V=fileContent`?

Comment: Let me check if I got that correct. You want to read files from S3, do some transformation/computation and write back to files on S3. You want to retain the same directory/file structure as before. Is that basically what you want to do? Do you want to overwrite the files you're reading from or create new files?

BTW, do you really have data for 22 years?

Comment: @GregaKešpret almost. Each day has on average 2500 files (but that varies a lot, we have many more files per day in recent history). In any case, we are in the "many small files" scenario. I want to bundle them in blocks of one day each, so we'll go from 20 million files to 8000, roughly. This will make further steps faster (much faster, by experience) than reading 20 million files.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just use a script to bundle them together and only then give the bundles as input to Spark? Is that viable in your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried something along the lines of sc.wholeTextFiles?

It creates an RDD where the key is the filename and the value is the byte array of the whole file. You can then map this so the key is the file date, and then groupByKey?

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

Comment: Indeed, this now works in Spark 1.2 with Hadoop 2.4, as I independently noticed a few days ago.  In an earlier version it was chocking on gzipped files (wholeTextFile would give the gzip byte data instead of gunzipping it and giving the text).

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

First You can get a Buffer/List of S3 Paths :

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import java.util.ArrayList
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectListing
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest

def listFiles(s3_bucket:String, base_prefix : String) = {
    var files = new ArrayList[String]

    //S3 Client and List Object Request
    var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
    var objectListing: ObjectListing = null;
    var listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest();

    //Your S3 Bucket
    listObjectsRequest.setBucketName(s3_bucket)

    //Your Folder path or Prefix
    listObjectsRequest.setPrefix(base_prefix)

    //Adding s3:// to the paths and adding to a list
    do {
      objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
      for (objectSummary <- objectListing.getObjectSummaries().asScala) {
        files.add("s3://" + s3_bucket + "/" + objectSummary.getKey());
      }
      listObjectsRequest.setMarker(objectListing.getNextMarker());
    } while (objectListing.isTruncated());

    //Removing Base Directory Name
    files.remove(0)

    //Creating a Scala List for same
    files.asScala
  }
```

Now Pass this List object to the following piece of code, note : sc is an object of SQLContext

```
var df: DataFrame = null;
  for (file <- files) {
    val fileDf= sc.textFile(file)
    if (df!= null) {
      df= df.unionAll(fileDf)
    } else {
      df= fileDf
    }
  }
```

Now you got a final Unified RDD i.e. df

Optional, And You can also repartition it in a single BigRDD

```
val files = sc.textFile(filename, 1).repartition(1)
```

Repartitioning always works :D

Answer (score 1):

At your scale, elegant solution would be a stretch.

I would recommend against using `sc.textFile("s3n://mybucket/path/txt/*/*/*/*.txt.gz")` as it takes forever. What you can do is use [AWS DistCp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) or something similar to move files into HDFS. Once its in HDFS, spark is quite fast in ingesting the information in whatever way suits you.

Note that most of these processes require some sort of file list so you'll need to generate that somehow. for 20 mil files, this creation of file list will be a bottle neck. I'd recommend creating a file that get appended with the file path, every-time a file gets uploaded to s3.

Same for output, put into hdfs and then move to s3 (although direct copy might be equally efficient).

Comment: This is the better solution